# Can Netty Split Fields Within Message?

Tags: java, netty

Netty can split a network packet to individual messages, but can it split fields within the message?

```
message delimeter = "\r\n"
field delimiter = ","

example network packet = "A,B,C\r\nD,E,F\r\n"
```

Example code:

```
val delimiterDecoder = new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Delimiters.lineDelimiter().apply(0))

val bootstrap = new Bootstrap

bootstrap.group(new OioEventLoopGroup())
  .channel(classOf[OioSocketChannel])
  .handler(new ChannelInitializer[SocketChannel]() {

  override def initChannel(channel: SocketChannel): Unit = {

    channel.pipeline().addLast(delimiterDecoder)

    channel.pipeline().addLast(new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.US_ASCII))

    channel.pipeline().addLast(new SimpleChannelInboundHandler[String] {

      override def messageReceived(channelHandlerContext: ChannelHandlerContext, message: String): Unit = {

        // Can Netty do this instead of using Guava?
        val message = Splitter.on(',').split(buffer).iterator()

      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Netty doesn't even know what a message is, let alone a field within a message.

Comment: @EJP Frame would be the better term over Message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no... What you may be able to do is adding two DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder decoders.. the first splitting on '\r\n' and the second on ','.

Comment: Problem with the proposed approach is that the Application level processing would be over complicated.  Accepted your answer with this in mind.